# Is it possible to inherit data from another table across schemas?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance

I'm trying to create a custom list of houses that a user can plot on a map. Each user can create houses, or edit the houses they've created. However there is a common set of houses that all users must have, and that can not be edited or deleted.

The users are divided into one schema per user, with a user.houses table listing all the custom houses for a single user.

Similarly, the public.houses table holds the houses available to every user. The structure of these tables are identical.

Is there a way to not duplicate the public.houses table data across all the user.houses tables?

I was able to use inheritance to ensure that the user.houses table exactly matches the public.houses table structure. Now I want to do this with the data as well.

```sql
INSERT INTO public.houses id VALUES (1), (2) ;
INSERT INTO user_a.houses id VALUES (3) ;
INSERT INTO user_b.houses id VALUES (4) ;

SELECT id FROM user_b.houses ;
```

I expect the output to be ids: [1, 2, 4]

Comment: You shouldn't have one table for each user, but a single table for all users with an `owner` column

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You may have already made a bad decision by having one schema per user.  There are some valid reasons for doing this -- security would be the number one reason.  If you had a strong requirement that the data be separated.  Another reason would be if the users were actually using different database versions (their own installations).

That said, it is usually better to support multiple users within a single databases/schema.  The tables would identify the user for each entity (where it is important).  Some tables, such as reference tables would be shared without ownership.

One thing that you can do is create views.  The view:

```
create view v_user_houses as
    select p.*
    from public.houses p
    union all
    select u.*
    from user.houses u;
```

You would need a separate view for each user.

An alternative would be to *copy* the publish houses into all the users table.  When anything changes in the pubic houses, then you would propagate those changes to the users houses tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT array_agg(a.id) FROM (
    select id from public.houses
    union all
    select id from user_a.houses
    union all
    select id from user_b.houses ) AS a
```